# How do I add a src in style class?

Tags: html, css, image

```
<div><img class="imgClose"></div>
```

I tried adding like this, but it does not show the image:

```
<style type="text/css">
.imgClose
{
   float: right;
   margin-top: -15px;
   background: 16px 16px no-repeat url(_assets/img/close.png);
}
</style>
```

If I add in the HTML, then it works, but I would like to put the `src` in style class instead.

```
<div><img class="imgClose" src="_assets/img/close.png"></div>
```

Comment: Are you missing the closing `>` in the live code as well? Or was that just a copy/paste issue?

Comment: @Mayankswami: i know it can be done but my question is adding src in class.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add element properties (like `src`) from the element styling.

Answer (score 1):

the .imgClose need a height and a width in order to display correctly...

when you put the src in the image, the div gets them automatticly, and thats you problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This would fail validation anyway. Your image tag will require a src attributes.
You can either add an empty div and apply your image as a background image or you need an image tag, you can add a transparent placeholder image and define it's dimensions and background image with css.
It's also better to add the dimension to the image so that the browser can render the page even when elements haven't been downloaded yet.

But the real question is why do you want to do that?

If you image is purely decorative you can add it as a background image.
If it is important in the Html, leave it as an image tag with src attribute.

I assume that you want to create a close button widgety thingy.
It might be better for you to add a link element with text content and style it with css and text replacement.

```
<a href="whatever" class="close-widgety-thingy">close the widget thing</a>
```

and in css

```
.close-widgety-thingy {
   text-indent: -12345em;
   width: 16px;
   height: 16px;
   background: transparent url(path/to/close/image.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Is it what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Use link tag and mention your css file path in href as below

```
 <link type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Desktop\style.css">
```

Answer (score -1):

You must specify the `width`, `height`, and `display:inline-block|block;` for the background of `img` to work correctly, without providing a `src` attribute. However, I would encourage the use of a different element, as the `img` element is specifically for using the `src` attribute.

```
<style type="text/css">
.imgClose {
 display:block;
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
 float: right;
 margin-top: -15px;
 background: 16px 16px no-repeat url(_assets/img/close.png);
}
</style>
```

Comment: This would work but its not an embeded image, its a div with an image background. You would not be able to right click to save image, ect.

Comment: @PhilipK, actually, the OP's HTML example shows `<div><img class="imgClose"></div>`, so the background should, in fact, be on the image. And it also **is possible** to save the background, even if it's set to an `img` without a `src` (tested in Firefox).